# How to use range date or range number with server side script (Jquery Datatable)

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

How to use range date or range number with server side script (Jquery Datatable)

i found this sample (jsfiddle.net/evcfespn/26) but when i use with server side script it not work !

Comment: please add code and exact error

Comment: here my source code => range date with server side script ( https://www.dropbox.com/s/o36fvjbrcnpv5js/datatable_range_date.rar )

Comment: in that file have 2 file. normal.php is normal data without server script and index.php is server side script. normal.php range date work fine but when i use with server side script it not work !

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, i.e., contain all the code needed to reproduce your problem (see [mcve]). It's very unlikely that anybody is going to download your code from an external source.